# Cannot login due to elementary OS thanks to Veracrypt and a possibly invalid volume

Tags: boot, greeter, mount

I have Freya with an encrypted partition and decided to try Veracrypt. It created a partition I'll named like /dev/mnt/veracrypt7. After fiddling with the app, I gave up thinking I'm already well served with my encrypted partition.

I tried to eject the mounted drive using Freya's file manager, which asked me to force eject, and I accepted. Then I went to veracrypt's windows and saw the volume still there, and could not eject it through it giving a "volume in use" error. The funny thing is, in elementary OS File manager the volume looks ejected, but if I click on it it will mount again without asking for a password. Unable to unmount it, I decided to reboot.

That's when the problem began. I can boot to Freya without a problem until the login screen. There, when I put the password and try to enter, the screen goes black for a second, then back to the login screen. I believe this happens because Pantheon could be trying to mount an inexistent partition, closed due to rebooting.

How could I verify what error is happening during the login? Is there a way to remove any references to the /dev/mnt/veracrypt7 partition so the system cannot try to mount it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to diagnose and fix the issue from another "virtual terminal".

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to drop to TTY1.
2. Enter you username, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then your password, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to log in.
3. Type `cat .xsession-errors` to view the contents of the `.xsession-errors` file.

Hopefully an error in there will help you diagnose the issue!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this enabled me to remove the disk from booting. However, it turns out that the encrypted swap partition got corrupted somehow so I had to reinstall everything... But thanks for the help again, I appreciate it.